# Why does this PHP for loop execute without a semicolon after the loop control?

Tags: php

Here is simple PHP code which executes without semicolon:

```
<?php
for($a=1; $a<=10;Print $a,$a++)
?>
```

How this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a
>   semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last
>   line of a PHP block.

See [PHP Instruction separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

Answer (score 4):

> As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. **The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon**; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php